# How to detect if browser tab has changed and refresh it if so

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, cross-browser

I need a cross-browser javaScript code (if possible) that detects when entering a browser's tab (crossing from current opened tab to another tab) and refresh its page when the change was made.

Comment: What change? What notification system do you have in place to refresh on changes?

Comment: lets say it doesn't matter what i will do in the event, i just want to know how to catch the tab change. (and in the event i will make an ajax call that will refresh the page)

Answer (score 1):

Window events can be in handy. So you can react to the blur and focus events, so leaving your browser tab will cause blur event and returning back - focus event.

```
$(window).focus(function(){
  //refresh your page here
});
```

Comment: Is there a way of adding an event listener that will be applied to all DOM elements on the page?

Comment: And it seems like the 'focus' event is being called too many times, i want an event that will be called only once - when entering the window after it loses focus and gaining it back. I also tried window.One("Focus", .....) but then the event will occur only one time...